# Interactive syntax-highligting: highlight the current region only

Tags: syntax-highlighting

Often enough a text file is structured as a collection of blocks or cells of some kind. E.g., slides in a Tex Beamer presentation, bibtex items, function definitions, etc.

I wonder if vim can facilitate highlighting of the current "cell" only, letting thereby the part I'm currently working on to stand out from the rest?

Comment: Maybe start from this plugin: https://github.com/junegunn/limelight.vim

Comment: @VanLaser: awesome plugin, almost does the job. I can definitely continue from there. Thank you for the advice!

Comment: @vbond if you decided to use limelight, please do post an answer about using it!

Comment: @vbond if you could provide an example of the syntax and it is a regexp you can write your own highlighting

Comment: @vbnod did you manage to extend limelight into what you wanted?  Is the code available?

Comment: @Rich: if you know how to apply the techniques given in the referenced question, I would be happy if you could post an answer here, e.g. using following beamer example file: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/master/doc/examples/a-conference-talk/beamerexample-conference-talk.tex#L91-L126. IMHO the question is clear enough what is meant. There is actually a related but unanswered issue on github for the plugin limelight: [limelight.vim/issues/38](https://github.com/junegunn/limelight.vim/issues/38).

Comment: @Hotschke I’ve retracted my close vote. Might be worth editing an example into the question?

Comment: @Rich. Sure, a short beamer example code, possibly with a faked screenshot of what it should look like, would make the question even clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to [focus](https://github.com/sindresorhus/focus), like this:

[image: sample]

Comment: Thanks @laktak. Nice one, although not quite what I meant: I need to highlight a part with all the syntax items in it. Nevertheless, good to know about the focus too.

Comment: You could try to look at http://vimawesome.com or update your question with an example.